# Show resized Base64 output of an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, filereader

I'm trying hard to accomplish and understand the following 'monstercode' that I wrote. Basically, this function should fire when the File input dialog (HTML) was fired. But the code goes well only a few lines. It loads the image, and then in the first `alert()` it shows me the base64 of the original image, but then, later in the code, when the actual image should be loaded in a canvas, it returns (in another `alert()`) height `0`, probably meaning that the image wasn't loaded correctly or at all.

The HTML input form (simplified) looks like this:

```
<input type='File' accept='image/*' onChange='changeBtn(this);' />
```

And the function below:

```
function changeBtn(elem) {
    selfile = document.getElementById(elem.id);

    if ('files' in selfile) {
        var file = selfile.files[0];
        if ('name' in file) {
            str1 = file.name;
        }
        if ('size' in file) {
            str1 += ' (' + ((file.size / 1024) / 1024).toFixed(2) + 'MB)';
        }
        document.getElementById("label_" + elem.id).innerHTML = str1;

        var FR= new FileReader();
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        FR.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            alert(e.target.result); // Returns B64 of the original image
        };

        FR.readAsDataURL(file);

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;
        alert(height); // Returns 0

        if (width > height) {
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else {
            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        alert(dataurl); // Returns only "data; " and nothing more

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Seems quite simple, but I don't get it. I rewrote the code at least 3 times, but I get always the same result.

Comment: Check your scoping of `img`. You define it, then use it outside of `onload` where it is still empty.

Comment: @J.Titus But when I put everything inside the onload, the onload seems to never complete.. (It shows no alerts)

Comment: It is not a scoping issue. You call `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` which will complete by issuing the callback to onload. However `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` returns immediately and continues executing your code whether the `img` variable got set up or not. If you move all the code that follows `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` inside the onload, it should work. It may not be the best way to do it but it is a start.

Comment: @markbernard "It is not a scoping issue.... If you move all the code that follows `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` inside the onload, it should work." - Code operating outside of a callback when it should be inside is not a scoping issue? :) When OP uses `img` for `img.width` and `img.height` it's still operating as a new `<img>`, so the width and height are 0. Inside the callback, this would be different.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Define "everything." As markbernard stated, `readAsDataURL()` should stay outside the callback. Everything after that should go inside.

Comment: @J.Titus No it is not a scoping issue. If it was img would be undefined. It is a timing issue. The code could remain outside if the timing was different or it was called after some delay. ie if you could call `FR.waitForLoad()` then it would work.

Comment: @markbernard I moved all the code after `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` into the `onload` event, still got `0` height and no output.

Comment: Also tried putting an `alert` before `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` to simulate a waitig (if it was a timing issue, it should work) - still no output.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!
I was calling `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` before loading the image into it, leading it to load an undefined file.

If we look at following code that has failed:

```
var FR= new FileReader();
var img = document.createElement("img");
FR.onload = function(e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;
    alert(e.target.result); // Returns B64 of the original image
};
FR.readAsDataURL(file);
```

we now know why. First `var FR= new FileReader();` is called, then `FR.readAsDataURL(file);` and then, at last, when the onload fires: `img.src = e.target.result;`. That's the wrong order. The right order is:

```
function changeBtn(elem) {
    selfile = document.getElementById(elem.id);

    if ('files' in selfile) {
        var file = selfile.files[0];
        if ('name' in file) {
            str1 = file.name;
        }
        if ('size' in file) {
            str1 += ' (' + ((file.size / 1024) / 1024).toFixed(2) + 'MB)';
        }
        document.getElementById("label_" + elem.id).innerHTML = str1;

        var FR= new FileReader();

        FR.readAsDataURL(file);

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        FR.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            alert(e.target.result);

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;
            alert(height);

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            alert(dataurl);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll make that shortly, I am just correcting some minor spelling errors in my answer. :)